# Jenssegers/laravel-mongodb transactions doesn't rollback

Tags: mongodb, transactions, laravel-8, jenssegers-mongodb

I need to use transactions in laravel 8 and I'm using the Jenssegers-laravel-mongodb package. The `beginTransaction` method on the DB facade doesn't work for mongoDB, so I tried the following method:

```
        $session = DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoClient()->startSession();
        $session->startTransaction();
        try {
            $task = Task::create($request->only('reminder', 'priority'));
            $activity = $task->activity()->create($request->only('topic', 'description', 'creator_id'));
            $session->commitTransaction();
        
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $session->abortTransaction();
        }
```

When a query fails in the `try` block, it throws the exception but does not roll back the transactions. I also found a similar question here: [Laravel mongodb transactions does not rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58499778/7440964). I tried the given solution in the single answer, but it returns the following error:

```
{message: "Unsupported driver [].", exception: "InvalidArgumentException"}
```